# Elegant solution for string-counting?

Tags: java

The problem I have is an example of something I've seen often.  I have a series of strings (one string per line, lets say) as input, and all I need to do is return how many times each string has appeared.  What is the most elegant way to solve this, without using a trie or other string-specific structure?  The solution I've used in the past has been to use a hashtable-esque collection of custom-made (String, integer) objects that implements Comparable to keep track of how many times each string has appeared, but this method seems clunky for several reasons:

1) This method requires the creation of a comparable function which is identical to the String's.compareTo().

2) The impression that I get is that I'm misusing TreeSet, which has been my collection of choice.  Updating the counter for a given string requires checking to see if the object is in the set, removing the object, updating the object, and then reinserting it.  This seems wrong.

Is there a more clever way to solve this problem? Perhaps there is a better Collections interface I could use to solve this problem?

Thanks.

Comment: Why don't you just use a HashMap of Strings to counts? You don't need sorting, and a they aren't "specific" to Strings, just anything with a equals() method and a hashcode() method.

Answer (score 1):

One posibility can be:

```
public class Counter {
    public int count = 1;
}

public void count(String[] values) {

    Map<String, Counter> stringMap = new HashMap<String, Counter>();

    for (String value : values) {
        Counter count = stringMap.get(value);
        if (count != null) {
            count.count++;
        } else {
            stringMap.put(value, new Counter());
        }
    }
}
```

In this way you still need to keep a map but at least you don't need to regenerate the entry every time you match a new string, you can access the Counter class, which is a wrapper of integer and increase the value by one, optimizing the access to the array

Comment: The Counter class should be declared *static* (presuming its meant as an inner class). Also, you start counting at zero for the first a string appears, naively I would expect to start counting at one. Nitpick end :)

Comment: Hi Durandal, thanks for your comment. About the initialization: you're right, I didn't check the code, it is edited now. About your suggestion, I'm sorry, I can't see the point of having an static nested class here, can you explain to me? My implementation of counter is only an example, but in this situation it is used only in this outer class.

Answer (score 0):

`TreeMap` is much better for this problem, or better yet, Guava's [`Multiset`](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/NewCollectionTypesExplained#Multiset).

To use a `TreeMap`, you'd use something like

```
Map<String, Integer> map = new TreeMap<>();
for (String word : words) {
   Integer count = map.get(word);
   if (count == null) {
     map.put(word, 1);
   } else {
     map.put(word, count + 1);
   }
}

// print out each word and each count:
for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry : map.entrySet()) {
  System.out.printf("Word: %s Count: %d%n", entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
}
Integer theCount = map.get("the");
if (theCount == null) {
  theCount = 0;
}
System.out.println(theCount); // number of times "the" appeared, or null
```

`Multiset` would be much simpler than that; you'd just write

```
Multiset<String> multiset = TreeMultiset.create();
for (String word : words) { 
  multiset.add(word);
}
for (Multiset.Entry<String> entry : multiset.entrySet()) {
  System.out.printf("Word: %s Count: %d%n", entry.getElement(), entry.getCount());
}
System.out.println(multiset.count("the")); // number of times "the" appeared
```

Comment: Why not HashMap? You don't need an order of the elements here.

Comment: The author seemed to be using tree-based collections, mentioning `TreeSet`, so I stuck with that.  Switching to `HashMap` or `HashMultiset` would work equally well, if ordering really didn't matter.

Comment: I would favor a `Map<String, int[]>`.  That way, updating the count associated with a word would simply require incrementing `count[0]` in-place rather than having to store a new `Integer` object every time.  If some other Framework type existed which encapsulated a mutable `int` field, that might be better that an `int[1]`, but I don't know of any.

Comment: @supercat: That gets significantly less readable for extracting values.  If you're going that far, you should be wrapping things in another type with a cleaner interface...like `Multiset`.

Comment: @supercat good idea, but it should be used only if performance is a problem, because of the readability and clarity.

Comment: @LouisWasserman: To extract the value associated with a string, `int[] counter = map.get(); int count = (counter == null) ? 0 : counter[0];`.  Would be cleaner if there were some way to test for null and grab the value in a single expression, but not too bad anyway.

Comment: @JakubHr: IMHO, frameworks really should include a `MutableIntHolder` type for this kind of thing, but they don't.  The speed and clarity of of `AtomicInteger` would probably be between that of using a `Map<String, Integer>` and that of a `Map<String, int[]>`.  For code to define its own `MutableIntHolder` type might be faster, but would require the reader to examine that particular type to determine its semantics (while the semantics of array subscripting are well-known).  One ends up with annoying null-handling requirements in any case no matter what one does.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a hash-map (no need to "create a comparable function"):

```
Map<String,Integer> count(String[] strings)
{
    Map<String,Integer> map = new HashMap<String,Integer>();
    for (String key : strings)
    {
        Integer value = map.get(key);
        if (value == null)
            map.put(key,1);
        else
            map.put(key,value+1);
    }
    return map;
}
```

Here is how you can use this method in order to print (for example) the string-count of your input:

```
Map<String,Integer> map = count(input);
for (String key : map.keySet())
    System.out.println(key+" "+map.get(key));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Bag data structure from the Apache Commons Collection, like the [HashBag](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections4/bag/HashBag.html).

A Bag does exactly what you need: It keeps track of how often an element got added to the collections.

```
HashBag<String> bag = new HashBag<>();
bag.add("foo");
bag.add("foo");
bag.getCount("foo"); // 2
```